# Why CMD+N opened new popup Terminal window doesn't follow the default preference?

Tags: macos, terminal

I love Mac terminal in Dark and had set up the default color scheme to a dark one. Every time I open the terminal it's OK but I found that if I open one terminal window and then open another one via <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> the new one still remains in the original white one.

How can I make sure every Terminal window I opened all in the default preferences?

I am using OS X 10.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this is an easily doable through normal terminal preferences.
Go to terminal>preferences>startup 
Here you can set the default behavior regarding window color scheme, including what color scheme new windows use.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same thing recently although I'm on OSX 10.6.8. To fix on my version, I did the following:

1. Terminal > Preferences > Settings
2. Select the desired style from the list on the left
3. Click the Default button below that list

Comment: Correct answer!